# If you have only 3 coins and 1 is a penny is it possible for you to have a Dollar?

Tags: arithmetic

If you have only 3 coins and 1 is a penny is it possible for you to have a Dollar?

Comment: At least a Dollar or exact one Dollar? What coins (values) are available?

Answer (score 3):

If it's a dollar or more, than Dominik has answered you. Yes there are dollar coins. However we can't have exactly $1$ dollar. If we had exactly $1$ dollar than that would require us to use coins lower than a dollar.
Coins with values:

$.01$

$.05$

$.1$

$.25$

$.50$

Since you already specified that one of the $3$ coins is a penny the other two should add up to $.99$.

We can't use two half dollars for an obvious reason.

And the next two coins of largest value would be $.5+.25$

But that isn't even enough to get to $.99$

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is. For example, you could have a penny, another penny and a dollar.

Note that the question asks whether it is possible to have a dollar; It *doesn't* ask whether it is possible for the sum of the values of your coins to be a a dollar.

Comment: Also: Three penny coins and a dollar *bill*

Comment: Also:  You could have three pennies, and also another ninety-seven pennies.